# git like library for VCM on .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, git, version-control, .net-core

I am looking git like solution for manage some configuration data using .net core 2.0 . It can be maybe lib for Git or something else solution but I don't find this. Can you help me?

Solution needs to feet following requirements:

- Ability to walk on history changesets (rollback to past, go forward to current state)
- Optionally conflict solving features (optionally, not a mandatory requirement)
- Ability to see all log (all history list)

Thanks for all possible answers!

Comment: Yes, you can version control your .net core 2.0 project/library in git repo. What's the problem you met when you manage with git repo?

Comment: I need to store NOT a source code in Git repo but configuration data, with ability to rollback to the history data directly from my C# code. There is a libs like Git# but I don't know weather it is working in .Net Core

Comment: What do you mean the configuration data? Do you get the "data" now?

Comment: "Data" is like kind of data in JSON format. It can be all data that JSON can store.

Comment: Git is a VCS which track the version of files in the git repo. Unless you have get the configuration data in json, then you can manage the json files in git repo.